# Не перебиваются стили

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Модальное окно до]

[image: Модальное окно после]

Подскажите пожалуйста, добавил обработчик события на кнопку:

```
    const modalTrigger = document.querySelector('[data-modal]');
    const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
    const modalCloseBtn = document.querySelector('[data-close]');
    
    modalTrigger.addEventListener('click',  () => {
        modal.classList.add('show');
        modal.classList.remove('hide');
    });

    modalCloseBtn.addEventListener('click',  () => {
        modal.classList.add('hide');
        modal.classList.remove('show');
    });
```

Есть вот такие стили:

```
.show {
    display: block;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Как сделать чтобы добавляемый класс, перебивал стили полученные до него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать свойство [более специфичным](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Например так:

```
.modal.show {
    display: block;
}
.modal.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Или описывать классы `.show` и `.hide` ниже, чем описан `.modal` в документе CSS.

Или задавать свойство `display` элементу:

```
modal.style.display = 'none';
modal.style.display = 'block';
```